# Definition of intersection of simplices

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

A singular $n$-simplex $\alpha: \Delta^n\rightarrow \Delta^p$ in $\Delta^p$ is called *affine* if $\alpha(\sum_{i=0}^n t_i e_i)= \sum_{i=0}^n t_i\alpha(e_i)$ holds for all $t_i$ with $\sum_{i=0}^n t_i=1$ and $t_i\geq 0$. Following Hatcher, given an affixe $n$-simplex $\alpha$, we set $v_i=\alpha(e_i)$ and write $[v_0,\ldots, v_n]$ for $\alpha$.

Let $K$ be a set of affine simplices in some fixed $\Delta^p$. In my definition of a simplicial complex $K$ we speak of the intersection $\sigma\cap\tau$ of two affine simplices $\sigma\cap \tau$, and require $\sigma\cap \tau\in K$.

What does $\sigma\cap\tau$ mean? What I can think of is that we intersect the convex sets $\operatorname{im}(\sigma)$ and $\operatorname{im}(\tau)$ and then require that there is a affine simplex in $K$ which has an image equal to this intersection. Is that correct? Implicitely we are identifying maps with their image.

Comment: Intersection of singular simplices isn't really a thing, but it makes more sense in a simplicial complex. Did you find this in Hatcher or somewhere else?

Comment: @ronno This is from my lecture notes. It starts with "In this section we mean by a simplex an affine singular simplex." And then defines a simplicial complex as a set of simplices that is closed under intersection, and closed under taking faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised that your lecture notes do not contain a proper definition of an affine simplex. An *affine* (or *geometric*) *$n$-simplex in a Euclidean space $\mathbb R^p$* is the convex hull $[v_0,\ldots,v_n ]$ of $n+1$ points ("vertices") $v_0,\ldots, v_n$ in general position (this means that the vectors $d_i = v_i - v_0$, $i = 1,\ldots, n$, are linearly independent). If you want, you can replace the ambient $\mathbb R^p$ by some fixed affine simplex $p$-simplex $\Delta^p$.

The requirement $\sigma \cap \tau \in K$ (more precisely, $\sigma \cap \tau = \emptyset$ or $\sigma \cap \tau \in K$) means that $\sigma \cap \tau$ has to be the convex hull of a set of vertices which are common vertices of both $\sigma$ and $\tau$.

See for example Chapter 1 of

- Munkres, James R. Elements of algebraic topology. CRC Press, 2018

Also see my answer to [What is the difference between cellular, simplicial and singular homology and their simplices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4500541)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helps. I am suprised too. The section on simpicial homology starts with a repetition of the definition of a **singular** affine simplex, and then defines a simplicial complex and by doing so considers "intersections of singular affine simplices".